# Jquery Mobile select refresh after ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a select box which is inside a collapsible. I am trying to make an ajax call and add options dynamically from the result. Unfortunately the refresh on the select doesn't work and options are still now shown. any pointers? I am using jquery mobile 1.1.rc2

```
$.getJSON(myurl, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
        myDropDown.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value));
    });
    myDropDown.selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

Comment: are you getting jSon from your ajax call ?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors showing up in your Developer Console?

Comment: Please update the thread with how your situation has changed if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [forcing the rebuild](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html) of your selectmenu?

```
//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```