# JQuery mobile - Dropdown dynamic options are not getting displayed

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am calling a AJAX web service, In the success callback function, I am adding options to a Dropdownlist dynamically. We are using JQuery Mobile in this application.

```
$("#mylist").append(
     $('<option id="myoption' + index + '"></option>').val(myobject.id).html(myobject.description)
            );

        });
        $('#mylist').trigger('change');
```

But, these options are not getting displayed immediately. Only when i click on any of other static options, Dynamic Options are getting visible.

I saw in few threads, suggesting to use trigger() or refreshmenu. But none of them are working. Is it due to callback function I am using?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: How is defined `#mylist`? What version of jQuery Mobile do you use?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177815/jquery-mobile-select-refresh-after-ajax-call-not-working

Comment: What does `.html(myobject.description)` do? Is it necessary?

Comment: I tried  $('#mylist').trigger('change');
 $('#mylist').selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.5. Here is my list declaration.  <select id="mylist" data-native-menu="false" multiple >
                <option>--- Please Select ---</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>C</option>
            </select>

Comment: Hi Dahl, That's to add description for the option element. That will be visible as the list option.

Comment: $('#mylist').selectmenu('refresh', true); should do the trick. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gwugcdqg/1/

Comment: Hi ezanker, can you extend this example with an webservice callback output? I suspect, due to call back function, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ezanker,

.selectmenu('refresh',true) is working. In my case, I was referring JQuery JS file twice. Once in higher version and second in lower version. It took lower version. In the lower version, selectmenu is not supported.

As soon as I remove the second incorrect JS reference, it worked.